# comparing plist keys

Tags: python, perl, shell

I am trying to add a sanity check with respect to API, which tends to change its structure somewhat very quickly, hence I am thinking of adding a routine check, which stores the json response in plist file with date+time, and hence with respect to key structures, compare with the previous date and see if anything changed. Is there any python, shell or perl script written to do this already? I don't want to re-invent the wheel, so thought someone might have already done this prior?

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:data-mining] as I could not see any data mining in this question. You want to compare two XML/PList files as far as I can tell, but that doesn't involve data mining (= data-driven statistics). Look for XML diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A quick CPAN search](https://metacpan.org/search?q=plist) reveals a couple modules for manipulating plists: [Data::Plist](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aPlist) and [Mac::Tie::PList](https://metacpan.org/module/Mac%3a%3aTie%3a%3aPList).  I don't know their quality.

Data::Plist treats the plist file like any other XML file.  Mac::Tie::PList uses the native Objective C interface which is likely to be more accurate but its Perl interface, Foundation/PerlObjCBridge, is only available from the perl which ships with OS X.